# Spawn balls randomly

Tags: java, android, random, libgdx

Im making a game where balls spawn randomly from each side of the smartphone screen, and I got it working although the balls spawn mostly on the top side of the screen and 2/10 times on the bottom and sides of the screen. Heres the code:

```
//creates the balls and sets their position as well as the random timer for each
private void spawnBalls1() {

    Rectangle ball1 = new Rectangle();
    ball1.x = MathUtils.random(639, 641);
    ball1.y = 720;
    ball1.width = 32;
    ball1.height = 32;
    balls1.add(ball1);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();

}

private void spawnBalls2() {

    Rectangle ball2 = new Rectangle();
    ball2.x = 0;
    ball2.y = MathUtils.random(359, 361);
    ball2.width = 32;
    ball2.height = 32;
    balls2.add(ball2);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}

private void spawnBalls3() {

    Rectangle ball3 = new Rectangle();
    ball3.x = MathUtils.random(639, 641);
    ball3.y = 0;
    ball3.width = 32;
    ball3.height = 32;
    balls3.add(ball3);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}

private void spawnBalls4() {

    Rectangle ball4 = new Rectangle();
    ball4.x = 1280;
    ball4.y = MathUtils.random(359, 361);
    ball4.width = 32;
    ball4.height = 32;
    balls4.add(ball4);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}


//draws the balls
    for (Rectangle ball1 : balls1) {

        batch.draw(Ball, ball1.x, ball1.y);
    }

    for (Rectangle ball2 : balls2) {

        batch.draw(Ball, ball2.x, ball2.y);
    }

    for (Rectangle ball3 : balls3) {

        batch.draw(Ball, ball3.x, ball3.y);
    }

    for (Rectangle ball4 : balls4) {

        batch.draw(Ball, ball4.x, ball4.y);
    }


// if the time minus the time of the last ball spawn is less than x then spawn another ball in a random place
    if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > 1000000000) spawnBalls1();

    Iterator<Rectangle> iter1 = balls1.iterator();
    while(iter1.hasNext()) {

        Rectangle balls1 = iter1.next();
        balls1.y -= 500 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (balls1.overlaps(square)) {

            score++;
            showScore = "Score: " + score;
            iter1.remove();
        }
    }

    // if the time minus the time of the last ball spawn is less than x then spawn another ball in a random place
    if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > 1000000000) spawnBalls2();

    Iterator<Rectangle> iter2 = balls2.iterator();
    while (iter2.hasNext()) {

        Rectangle balls2 = iter2.next();
        balls2.x += 500 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (balls2.overlaps(square)) {

            score++;
            showScore = "Score: " + score;
            iter2.remove();
        }
    }

    // if the time minus the time of the last ball spawn is less than x then spawn another ball in a random place
    if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > 1000000000) spawnBalls3();

    Iterator<Rectangle> iter3 = balls3.iterator();
    while(iter3.hasNext()) {

        Rectangle balls3 = iter3.next();
        balls3.y += 500 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (balls3.overlaps(square)) {

            score++;
            showScore = "Score: " + score;
            iter3.remove();
        }
    }

    // if the time minus the time of the last ball spawn is less than x then spawn another ball in a random place
    if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > 1000000000) spawnBalls4();

    Iterator<Rectangle> iter4 = balls4.iterator();
    while(iter4.hasNext()) {

        Rectangle balls4 = iter4.next();
        balls4.x -= 500 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (balls4.overlaps(square)) {

            score++;
            showScore = "Score: " + score;
            iter4.remove();
        }
    }
```

What should I do/change to make them spawn randomly on each side?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Question: why are you using nanos rather than milliseconds?

Comment: @Draco18s because then it takes a lot for them to spawn

Comment: Well if you didn't divided all of your timers by a million, then I could see why.

Comment: The reasoning doesn't make sense to me. You can type a smaller number. Use seconds. `if (time < 1f)` will be essentially the same and a lot easier to read and manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All four of your ball spawning methods share the same `lastDropTime` variable. The execution time between

```
if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > 1000000000) spawnBalls1();
```

and

```
if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > 1000000000) spawnBalls4();
```

is going to be a tiny percentage of 1000000000 ns, so it's going to be very unlikely for spawnBalls2-4 ever to get called.

You should only have one test instead of four, and randomly pick one of the methods. Something like this:

```
if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > 1000000000){
    switch (MathUtils.randomInt(4)){
        case 0: spawnBalls1(); break;
        case 1: spawnBalls2(); break;
        case 2: spawnBalls3(); break;
        case 3: spawnBalls4(); break;
    }
}
```

Also, this is a lot of copy-paste code, which is ballooning your time investment. You ought to write one `spawnBalls` method that takes some parameter that affects where it places the balls.

Comment: oh right!! yeah thanks!!! im still kinda new to this, i'll get better with the progression of time. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
private void spawnBalls1() {

    Rectangle ball1 = new Rectangle();
    ball1.x = MathUtils.random(0, 641);
    ball1.y = MathUtils.random(0, 720);
    ball1.width = 32;
    ball1.height = 32;
    balls1.add(ball1);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();

}
```

Comment: This would spawn the ball just somewhere on the screen... I think he means somethin like `int wall=random.nextInt(4); switch(wall){case 0: spawnBalls1();...}`

Comment: @S.Klumpers no, the problem here is that spawnBalls1 is spawning them a lot more than the spawnBalls2, spawnBalls3 and spawnBalls4. I want them to spawn the balls the same times as spawnBalls1 but not at the same time

Comment: Then I think @ctst 's comment is the answer your looking for.

Comment: By the way, where are you calling `spawnBalls1()` from, it isn't in your code segment.

Comment: @gaffix: the same answer Tenfour wrote out.